# Theming a node edit Form - Move Author Information to another positon

Tags: theming, nodes, forms

I am theming the DRUPAL 7 NODE EDIT FORM following the instructions in the [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/drupal-commerce-theming-the-add-products-form-bulk-production-creation).

Everything is working fine.

However, I want to move the "Authoring Information" from the bottom of the page to another position on my node. How do I do that?

I thought I would be able to use this:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['author']); ?>
```

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: Make sure you clear the cache, if you modify your templates. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found to this was to use a View.

- In Views under relationship, select Content: Author The in fields,
  add an author field.
- Then in under Contextual Filters select Content
  NID
- Use the following settings for Content NID: WHEN THE FILTER VALUE
  IS NOT AVAILABLE: Provide Default Value / NODE ID from URL

Then simply create a block and display it on the node page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (Drupal 7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['author']['name']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['author']['date']); ?>
```

The author fieldset is part of the additional_settings group.  To render the author field you have to call it directly.

Display Suite is great, but it won't let you access the author field directly.