# How to custom theme Inline Entity Form (IEF) - using a .tpl.php file

Tags: theming, forms, entities

Is there a way to theme the Inline Entity Form (IEF) for example creating a .tpl.php file for that form and just declaring it on the theme's template.php?

I wanted to create a .tpl.php specifically since I want to add in custom codes in the form like, views, a little html, jquery and css.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup. it's possible. Read the following:http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97461/inline-entity-form-how-to-theme-the-referenced-form-edit-screen-with-a-tpl-php
bye

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Inline Entity form supports that. You could alter the behaviour of the form itself though with

```
 function THEMENAME_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {
   // your alters
}
```